# Windows 10: is it possible to add new notification to action center manually?

Tags: windows, notifications

is it possible manually to add/create new notification in the action center?
To set time when to show the notification?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: What do you mean by manually ? Create a notification with just a little program ?
And notifications can be scheduled with the `ScheduledToastNotification`.

Comment: It will be nice to have a program. May be it already exists?

Answer (score 20):

You can look at [this sample](https://gist.github.com/altrive/72594b8427b2fff16431) : this is a powershell script that raise a notification and as it is just a script, it is easy to use.

You can also write a minimalist C# console app that can raise a notification ([sample here](https://gist.github.com/k94ll13nn3/f3dce111e525a02c2bc9)). The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts).

Comment: Documentation link [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts)